# UNIX time conversion swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert sunrise and sunset time to "hh:mm AM/PM" format in iOS using swift.

Here is what I have,

UNIX time: 1456239086 (This is the sunrise time for LA)

```
func unixTimeConvertion(unixTime: Double) -> String {
    let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTime)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
}
```

The issue I ran into is, no matter what city I used, Tokyo, Beijing, Boston.  After the conversion, the "hh:mm AM/PM" is always local time at my location.  For example, I'm at New York, I get the sunrise time for Boston is "6:39 AM", which is correct.  When I request the sunrise time for Beijing, it shows "5:39 PM".  Based on my knowledge, it means when it is local time 5:39 PM at New York, sun rises in Beijing.

Comment: What API are you using to get the sunrise time?

Comment: @skyline75489 forecast.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds that have passed since a specific point in time.  Therefore, in my situation, a timezone information is needed.

Here are updated code that solves the problem.

```
func unixTimeConvertion(unixTime: Double) -> String {
    let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTime)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: timeZoneInfo)
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: NSLocale.systemLocale().localeIdentifier)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
}
```

timeZoneInfo contains the timezone information, for example "America/Los_Angeles".

Please let me know if there is a better way. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to point out that https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools is a great tool when it comes date conversion.